# 301 Redirect on older Joomla SEF URLS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, seo

I am working on removing an old Joomla 1.0 site that has the SEF module installed.   I need to redirect the URLs to static pages in a search engine friendly way.

A typical URL looks like:  www.mysite.com/index.php?/this-page.html.
I need to forward it to a static page on the same site like: www.mysite.com/this-page.html

So, I edited htaccess to read:

```
redirect 301 /index.php?/this-page.html http://www.mysite.com/this-page.html
```

The redirect does not seem to work.  Any ideas?   A wild card redirect to strip out the "/index.php?/"  would be a bonus since I have to do about 80.  I'm happy to do them manually, too.

Answer (score 0):

try this below and let me know

```
redirect /index.php?/this-page.html http://www.mysite.com/this-page.html
```

Comment: Removing the '301' didn't work.  I think the problem is the combination of ?/ .   Good idea, though.

Comment: yeah it could be. it worked for me when I removed the 301. That's why I suggested you that. By the way do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors.  It redirects everything to index.php and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your .htaccess 
Redirect /path/to/new/folder http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html

The firs argument should be the path to the folder

Comment: Thanks, just tried it.  It still just jumps to index.php.  redirect does not seem to recognize the weird ?/ instead of the more standard ?=

Comment: /index.php?/this-page.html is the product of a joomla page that is using SEF URLs, the actual url can be /index.php?option=com_extension&view=anything&layout=default. Maybe you should try that one

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) /$1 [R,L]

This eliminates index.php from all old sef urls